# Environment variables in codebuild project are overridden by action level when using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, cicd

I am using CDK to deploy codepipeline and codebuild to AWS. I found the environment variables in project level are completely replaced by action level.

Below is the code:

```
new actions.CodeBuildAction({
          actionName,
          type: actions.CodeBuildActionType.BUILD,
          input,
          outputs,
          project:
            new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, name, {
              projectName: name,
              environment: {
                ...
              },
              environmentVariables: envs,
              role: this.codeBuildRole,
              buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename(specFile),
            }),
          environmentVariables: additionalEnvs,
          runOrder:1,
        });
```

as you can see above code, there are two `environmentVariables` configurations one under `CodeBuildAction` and one is under `PipelineProject`. Based on AWS doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline-actions.CodeBuildActionProps.html#environmentvariables,

```
(optional, default: No additional environment variables are specified.)

The environment variables to pass to the CodeBuild project when this action executes.

If a variable with the same name was set both on the project level, and here, this value will take precedence.
```

the `environmentVariables` under CodeBuildAction should be additional variables. But what happens is the environment variable list in the codebuild project becomes empty. During execution, the environment variables on the running codebuild project only have the ones from the action level. It seems it is a complete replacement rather than appending. Does anyone know what I did wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, open an issue at https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk with a minimal peproducible example.

Comment: After synth-ing, search the  `.template.json` in `cdk.out` for "EnvironmentVariables".  There should be multiple `EnvironmentVariables` keys in the template, one in the `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` definition (an array of objects) and a further `EnvironmentVariables` key for each action in `AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline` (stringified arrays).  Not what you see?